# Nestjs UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: this.flushLogs is not a function

Tags: node.js, typescript, microservices

I want to learn how to create microservices with kafka and nestjs. But I got error like below

```
[Nest] 61226   - 07/18/2021, 12:12:16 PM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 61226   - 07/18/2021, 12:12:16 PM   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +27ms
[Nest] 61226   - 07/18/2021, 12:12:16 PM   [ServerKafka] INFO [Consumer] Starting {"timestamp":"2021-07-18T05:12:16.850Z","logger":"kafkajs","groupId":"group-account-server"}
[Nest] 61226   - 07/18/2021, 12:12:41 PM   [ServerKafka] INFO [ConsumerGroup] Consumer has joined the group {"timestamp":"2021-07-18T05:12:41.984Z","logger":"kafkajs","groupId":"group-account-server","memberId":"nestjs-consumer-server-d90648a1-60cf-4c23-8237-94ab2ea106d5","leaderId":"nestjs-consumer-server-d90648a1-60cf-4c23-8237-94ab2ea106d5","isLeader":true,"memberAssignment":{},"groupProtocol":"RoundRobinAssigner","duration":25120}
(node:61226) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: this.flushLogs is not a function
    at /Users/skinnyguy/Projects2020/microservices-lamexpress/kafka-services/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/nest-microservice.js:88:26
    at ServerKafka.listen (/Users/skinnyguy/Projects2020/microservices-lamexpress/kafka-services/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/server/server-kafka.js:43:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:61226) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:61226) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

How to solve this error ?

This my main.ts file

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { MicroserviceOptions } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { KafkaConsumerOptions } from './infrastructure/kafka/kafka.config';

async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

    app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(KafkaConsumerOptions);

    await app.startAllMicroservicesAsync();
    await app.listen(3000);
    console.log(`Application running in url ${app.getUrl()}`);
}
bootstrap();
```

And this my Kafka configurations

```js
import {
    ClientOptions,
    MicroserviceOptions,
    Transport,
} from '@nestjs/microservices';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

export const KafkaConsumerOptions: MicroserviceOptions = {
    transport: Transport.KAFKA,
    options: {
        client: {
            brokers: [process.env.KAFKA_HOST],
        },
        // list of consumer
        consumer: {
            groupId: 'group-account',
        },
    },
};
```

Has anyone here ever created microservices with kafka and nestjs ? Please share. Thank you

Comment: Problem is solved

Comment: How did you solve it @Didot?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check your nestjs version. @nestjs/microservices must be the same version as @nestjs/core

Comment: that was exactly it

Comment: Simple, but this should be the proper way to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Updating @nestjs/core and @nestjs/common packages to the latest version worked for me.

```
npm i @nestjs/core@latest @nestjs/common@latest
```